# I am unable to run jQuery, although regular Javascript works

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#bar_one").hover(function(){
        $(this).addClass("highlight")
    });
});
```

This is my jQuery, inserted into my webpage with an external link, which I know for a fact works, because regular Javascript works fine. I want to know why my jQuery will not work. Thanks!

Comment: have you included the jQuery library like `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.js"></script>`.. any error in your browser console

Comment: Can you show how you include jQuery in your code?

Comment: Can you show your full html code.

Comment: The jquery works: http://jsfiddle.net/Le9jt3pu/1/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/b6Lq10bv/

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/t3jheqjy/

Comment: See if jquery other function are working or not, are you using different javascript library, maybe they would be conflicting. Or you could have not included the jquery library

Answer (score 0):

You should include Jquery library before Jquery code like:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Check Here in [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t3jheqjy/5/). it's work with your code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#bar_one").hover(function(){
        $(this).addClass("highlight")
    });
});

<div id="bar_one">Test</div>
```